# how to apply different layouts to different pages in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal

I have converted a HTML page to *Drupal* template by using blocks and `page.tpl.php` file. Now I have another page that I need to convert and link it to the main navigation menu.

The problem is, that another page have completely different layouts and I don't understand how to create that layout and link it to the main menu. Is it really so complex? I found that it can be done by using panels but I am completely new in *Drupal*. I need a simple solution. Thanks if anyone can help me.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/theming

Answer (score 1):

You can use some module like [display suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) or [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) to create custom new pages with custom layout.

If you want to make all with code (and avoid database configurations), panels module is fully compatible with [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) (I don't know compatibility with display suite).

Comment: I don't think that he means pages in drupal's terminology, but different content types.

Comment: Panels is useful both for creating custom layouts for isolated pages and for content types. Even other entity pages such as taxonomy terms.